# S3 select aws console

Tags: amazon-s3-select

I have the following data in a file:

```
{"new_date":"2022-06-09","code":34,"value":33,"id":18}
{"new_date":"2022-06-09","code":34,"value":36,"id":19}
{"new_date":"2022-06-09","code":34,"value":35,"id":15}
```

In AWS console im trying to execute the following code, is it possible to do between date comparison in s3 select?

```
SELECT s.* FROM s3object s WHERE CAST(new_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') >= '2022-06-09' limit 5
```

but i cant seem to get this work, from the docs i have found that there is a BETWEEN available, but how does that work?

Comment: You can try this way: SELECT s.*
FROM s3object s
WHERE s.new_date >= '2022-06-09'
LIMIT 5